# Remove class and disabled attribute on load

Tags: jquery

The following code removes the disabled attribute and class when a value is input into the text field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name="passed_to_pwks"]').blur(function() {
    var that = $('[name="save_email"]')[0];
    if (this.value != '') {
      this.disabled = true;
      that.disabled = false;
      $('button').removeClass('ebc-disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

How Do I run the same jQuery on page load? I want the button enabled and class to remain if there's data in that field when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and call that on $(document).ready

```
 function isDataAvailable(){
   var dataField= $('[name="passed_to_pwks"]')[0];
   var that = $('[name="save_email"]')[0];
   if (dataField.value != '') {
      dataField.disabled = true;
      that.disabled = false;
      $('button').removeClass('ebc-disabled');
   }
 }
```

And call this function like

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    isDataAvailable();

    $('[name="passed_to_pwks"]').blur(function() {
    var that = $('[name="save_email"]')[0];
     if (this.value != '') {
      this.disabled = true;
      that.disabled = false;
      $('button').removeClass('ebc-disabled');
    }
  });
});
```